# Showing limit points of $Y \times X$ with a dictionary order and order topology

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I did everything else, I am left over with (6). For 6, I did this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My prof said that I have to construct the special cases too, just like $\big[ (0,0),(0,1) \big)$, if I take this, then $(0,0)$ won't be a limit point. I tried doing for others but got confused in the next 2 parts and also I can't get it.
Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so we have the Double Arrow (as is the traditional name for this $[0,1]\times \{0,1\}$ space, due to Aleksandroff and Urysohn, early 20th century).

This space has a minimum $(0,0)$ and a maximum $(1,1)$, so there get slightly different neighbourhoods in the order topology. Every point of the form $(x,0)$ has a direct right hand neighbour $(x,1)$, with no points inbetween (a so-called "jump", showing the space is disconnected), while points of the form $(x,1)$ have no such right neighbour.

Starting with $(0,0)$: one basic neighbourhood of it is $\left[(0,0),(0,1)\right) = \{(0,0)\}$ so that is an isolated (non-limit) point.

Similarly $(1,1)$ has a basic neighbourhood $\left((1,0),(1,1)\right]=\{(1,1)\}$ so that too is an isolated non-limit point.

Now consider a point of the form $(x,1)$with $x< 1$ (so not the maximum); its basic neighbourhoods are open intervals, say $I=\left((a,i), (b,j)\right)$ containing $(x,1)$, which implies $a <  x$ or $a=x,i=0$ and $b>x$. Pick any $x< b' < b$ and note that $(b',0) \in I \setminus \{(x,1)\}$ so that $(x,1)$ is a limit point of $[0,1]\times \{0,1\}$. In fact we see we can take basic neighbourhoods where $(a,i)=(x,0)$ and $I$ reduces to $[(x,1), (b,j))$, so upper-points (except the maximum) all have right facing half-open intervals as basic open sets, essentially. This can be used to show that the subspace $(0,1) \times \{1\}$is homeomorphic to the Sorgenfrey line (what Munkres' calles the lower limit topology on $\Bbb R$) in the subspace topology...

Considerations for $(x,0)$ points with $x >0$ are similar : basic open sets are intervals $I=\left((a,i),(b,j)\right)$ again containing $(x,0)$, it follows that $a < x$ and $b >x$ or $b=x,j=1$. Again $a < a' < x$ exists, and $(a',0) \in I\setminus \{(x,0)\}$ so $(x,0)$ is a limit point of the space. Basic open sets can be chosen even smaller, taking $(x,1)$ as the right hand limit, so we get $I=\left((a,i),(x,0)\right]$ for all lower-points, except the minimum.

So the space consists of two isolated points at the extreme end with an intertwined copy of the Sorgenfrey line up (with added "minimum" $(0,1)$, and the reverse Sorgenfrey line down (with added "maximum" $(1,0)$), all of whose points are limit points both in their subspace as well as in the whole space.

Comment: So, according to ur description, it looks like (0,0) and (1,1) are not limit points of YxX, what about the rest? Will [1,1) also be a non limit point?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun I explicitly said they were non-limit (isolated ) points. The rest is not. That’s what I showed, didn’t I ?

Comment: I got you, so only (0,0) and (1,1) are not limit points, other than that everything else is a LP of (Y X X). Thanks a lot for your explanation.